# Extremely slow query on 1st run, even with indexes

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-optimization, query-performance

I have an extremely slow query that is slow despite indexes being used(on the order of 1-3 minutes). Similar queries will be run 4-6 times by the user, so speed is critical.

QUERY:

```
            SELECT SUM(bh.count) AS count,b.time AS batchtime
            FROM
              batchtimes AS b
            INNER JOIN batchtimes_headlines AS bh ON b.hashed_id = bh.batchtime_hashed_id
            INNER JOIN headlines_ngrams AS hn ON bh.headline_hashed_id = hn.headline_hashed_id
            INNER JOIN ngrams AS n ON hn.ngram_hashed_id = n.hashed_id
            INNER JOIN homepages_headlines AS hh ON bh.headline_hashed_id = hh.headline_hashed_id
            INNER JOIN homepages AS hp ON hh.homepage_hashed_id = hp.hashed_id
            WHERE
              b.time IN (SELECT * FROM generate_series('2013-10-10 20:00:00.000000'::timestamp,'2014-02-16 20:00:00.000000'::timestamp,'1 hours'))
              AND ( n.gram = 'a' )
              AND hp.url = 'www.abcdefg.com'
            GROUP BY
              b.time
            ORDER BY
              b.time ASC;
```

EXPLAIN ANALYZE after very first run:

```
GroupAggregate  (cost=6863.26..6863.79 rows=30 width=12) (actual time=90905.858..90908.889 rows=3039 loops=1)
 ->  Sort  (cost=6863.26..6863.34 rows=30 width=12) (actual time=90905.853..90906.971 rows=19780 loops=1)
     Sort Key: b."time"
     Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 1696kB
     ->  Hash Join  (cost=90.16..6862.52 rows=30 width=12) (actual time=378.784..90890.636 rows=19780 loops=1)
           Hash Cond: (b."time" = generate_series.generate_series)
           ->  Nested Loop  (cost=73.16..6845.27 rows=60 width=12) (actual time=375.644..90859.059 rows=22910 loops=1)
                 ->  Nested Loop  (cost=72.88..6740.51 rows=60 width=37) (actual time=375.624..90618.828 rows=22910 loops=1)
                       ->  Nested Loop  (cost=42.37..4391.06 rows=1 width=66) (actual time=368.993..54607.402 rows=1213 loops=1)
                             ->  Nested Loop  (cost=42.23..4390.18 rows=5 width=99) (actual time=223.681..53051.774 rows=294787 loops=1)
                                   ->  Nested Loop  (cost=41.68..4379.19 rows=5 width=33) (actual time=223.643..49403.746 rows=294787 loops=1)
                                         ->  Index Scan using by_gram_ngrams on ngrams n  (cost=0.56..8.58 rows=1 width=33) (actual time=17.001..17.002 rows=1 loops=1)
                                               Index Cond: ((gram)::text = 'a'::text)
                                         ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on headlines_ngrams hn  (cost=41.12..4359.59 rows=1103 width=66) (actual time=206.634..49273.363 rows=294787 loops=1)
                                               Recheck Cond: ((ngram_hashed_id)::text = (n.hashed_id)::text)
                                               ->  Bitmap Index Scan on by_ngramhashedid_headlinesngrams  (cost=0.00..40.84 rows=1103 width=0) (actual time=143.430..143.430 rows=294787 loops=1)
                                                     Index Cond: ((ngram_hashed_id)::text = (n.hashed_id)::text)
                                   ->  Index Scan using by_headlinehashedid_homepagesheadlines on homepages_headlines hh  (cost=0.56..2.19 rows=1 width=66) (actual time=0.011..0.011 rows=1 loops=294787)
                                         Index Cond: ((headline_hashed_id)::text = (hn.headline_hashed_id)::text)
                             ->  Index Scan using by_hashedid_homepages on homepages hp  (cost=0.14..0.17 rows=1 width=33) (actual time=0.005..0.005 rows=0 loops=294787)
                                   Index Cond: ((hashed_id)::text = (hh.homepage_hashed_id)::text)
                                   Filter: ((url)::text = 'www.abcdefg.com'::text)
                                   Rows Removed by Filter: 1
                       ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on batchtimes_headlines bh  (cost=30.51..2333.86 rows=1560 width=70) (actual time=7.977..29.674 rows=19 loops=1213)
                             Recheck Cond: ((headline_hashed_id)::text = (hn.headline_hashed_id)::text)
                             ->  Bitmap Index Scan on by_headlinehashedid_batchtimesheadlines  (cost=0.00..30.12 rows=1560 width=0) (actual time=6.595..6.595 rows=19 loops=1213)
                                   Index Cond: ((headline_hashed_id)::text = (hn.headline_hashed_id)::text)
                 ->  Index Scan using by_hashedid_batchtimes on batchtimes b  (cost=0.28..1.74 rows=1 width=41) (actual time=0.009..0.009 rows=1 loops=22910)
                       Index Cond: ((hashed_id)::text = (bh.batchtime_hashed_id)::text)
           ->  Hash  (cost=14.50..14.50 rows=200 width=8) (actual time=3.130..3.130 rows=3097 loops=1)
                 Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 121kB
                 ->  HashAggregate  (cost=12.50..14.50 rows=200 width=8) (actual time=1.819..2.342 rows=3097 loops=1)
                       ->  Function Scan on generate_series  (cost=0.00..10.00 rows=1000 width=8) (actual time=0.441..0.714 rows=3097 loops=1)
```

Total runtime: 90911.001 ms

EXPLAIN ANALYZE after 2nd run:

```
GroupAggregate  (cost=6863.26..6863.79 rows=30 width=12) (actual time=3122.861..3125.796 rows=3039 loops=1)
 ->  Sort  (cost=6863.26..6863.34 rows=30 width=12) (actual time=3122.857..3123.882 rows=19780 loops=1)
     Sort Key: b."time"
     Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 1696kB
     ->  Hash Join  (cost=90.16..6862.52 rows=30 width=12) (actual time=145.396..3116.467 rows=19780 loops=1)
           Hash Cond: (b."time" = generate_series.generate_series)
           ->  Nested Loop  (cost=73.16..6845.27 rows=60 width=12) (actual time=142.406..3102.864 rows=22910 loops=1)
                 ->  Nested Loop  (cost=72.88..6740.51 rows=60 width=37) (actual time=142.395..3011.768 rows=22910 loops=1)
                       ->  Nested Loop  (cost=42.37..4391.06 rows=1 width=66) (actual time=142.229..2969.144 rows=1213 loops=1)
                             ->  Nested Loop  (cost=42.23..4390.18 rows=5 width=99) (actual time=135.799..2142.666 rows=294787 loops=1)
                                   ->  Nested Loop  (cost=41.68..4379.19 rows=5 width=33) (actual time=135.768..437.824 rows=294787 loops=1)
                                         ->  Index Scan using by_gram_ngrams on ngrams n  (cost=0.56..8.58 rows=1 width=33) (actual time=0.030..0.031 rows=1 loops=1)
                                               Index Cond: ((gram)::text = 'a'::text)
                                         ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on headlines_ngrams hn  (cost=41.12..4359.59 rows=1103 width=66) (actual time=135.732..405.943 rows=294787 loops=1)
                                               Recheck Cond: ((ngram_hashed_id)::text = (n.hashed_id)::text)
                                               ->  Bitmap Index Scan on by_ngramhashedid_headlinesngrams  (cost=0.00..40.84 rows=1103 width=0) (actual time=72.570..72.570 rows=294787 loops=1)
                                                     Index Cond: ((ngram_hashed_id)::text = (n.hashed_id)::text)
                                   ->  Index Scan using by_headlinehashedid_homepagesheadlines on homepages_headlines hh  (cost=0.56..2.19 rows=1 width=66) (actual time=0.005..0.005 rows=1 loops=294787)
                                         Index Cond: ((headline_hashed_id)::text = (hn.headline_hashed_id)::text)
                             ->  Index Scan using by_hashedid_homepages on homepages hp  (cost=0.14..0.17 rows=1 width=33) (actual time=0.003..0.003 rows=0 loops=294787)
                                   Index Cond: ((hashed_id)::text = (hh.homepage_hashed_id)::text)
                                   Filter: ((url)::text = 'www.abcdefg.com'::text)
                                   Rows Removed by Filter: 1
                       ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on batchtimes_headlines bh  (cost=30.51..2333.86 rows=1560 width=70) (actual time=0.015..0.031 rows=19 loops=1213)
                             Recheck Cond: ((headline_hashed_id)::text = (hn.headline_hashed_id)::text)
                             ->  Bitmap Index Scan on by_headlinehashedid_batchtimesheadlines  (cost=0.00..30.12 rows=1560 width=0) (actual time=0.013..0.013 rows=19 loops=1213)
                                   Index Cond: ((headline_hashed_id)::text = (hn.headline_hashed_id)::text)
                 ->  Index Scan using by_hashedid_batchtimes on batchtimes b  (cost=0.28..1.74 rows=1 width=41) (actual time=0.003..0.004 rows=1 loops=22910)
                       Index Cond: ((hashed_id)::text = (bh.batchtime_hashed_id)::text)
           ->  Hash  (cost=14.50..14.50 rows=200 width=8) (actual time=2.982..2.982 rows=3097 loops=1)
                 Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 121kB
                 ->  HashAggregate  (cost=12.50..14.50 rows=200 width=8) (actual time=1.771..2.311 rows=3097 loops=1)
                       ->  Function Scan on generate_series  (cost=0.00..10.00 rows=1000 width=8) (actual time=0.439..0.701 rows=3097 loops=1)
```

Total runtime: 3125.985 ms

I have a 32GB server. Here are the modifications to postgresql.conf:

- default_statistics_target = 100
- maintenance_work_mem = 1920MB
- checkpoint_completion_target = 0.9
- effective_cache_size = 16GB
- work_mem = 160MB
- wal_buffers = 16MB
- checkpoint_segments = 32
- shared_buffers = 7680MB

DB has recently been Vacuumed, re-indexed, and analyze.

Any suggestions for how to tune this query?

Comment: Only line that really raises a flag for me is "b.time IN (SELECT * FROM generate_series('2013-10-10 20:00:00.000000'::timestamp,'2014-02-16 20:00:00.000000'::timestamp,'1 hours'))"...what are you accomplishing with that line?

Comment: Your statistics are off. Start by using `VACUUM ANALYZE` on all relevant tables (do you heve keys/indexes ?)

Comment: The UI lets the user select start, end, and interval. The generate_series part is dynamically generated based on that user input. That part goes very fast according to the EXPLAIN ANALYZE, so I don't think that is the issue.

Comment: @wildplasser That's a good point. I ran Vacuum Analyze but the statistics are still way off with the query. The tables all have indexes and keys which are used. I will try increasing the number of statistics collected by the query planner to see what happens.

Comment: Would it be an option to create a temporary table first to hold the output of the generate_series() (with PK) and include it as a JOIN ? If so, how would that affect the EXPLAIN? Also, would it help to move e.g. `n.gram = 'a'` from the `WHERE` to the relevant `JOIN` ?

Comment: BTW what is the actual granularity / resolution of `b.time` ? Why not use `b.time >= 2013-10-01 AND b.time < '2014-02-17` (and maybe add some date_trunc() somwhere before aggregation) ? BTW: your work_mem is **very** high (and not needed by this query) How many active sessions do you have ? What does vmstat/top say?

Comment: Add me to the list who thinks `generate_series` is fishy. Surely you can get what you want with `BETWEEN` and this will also let you do nice things with an index on `b.time`. Side note: using reserved words like "time" for column names is legal, but it will come back to bite you in the butt.

Comment: @wildplasser b.time holds time in 1 hour increments. This app is not live, so only 1 active session.

Comment: @AndrewLazarus Generate series just creates a set of individual times. Won't this also use the index on b.time? It's a well-documented postgres function: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-srf.html

Comment: @deroby Good questions. Creating a temporary table(using WITH) seems to improve the row statistics, but the query speed itself doesn't seem  to improve. No effect when moving the JOIN condition.

Comment: I narrowed down the problem to the table batchtimes_headlines. This table has 100,000,000 rows, so maybe it's just destined to be slow?

Comment: @JustAFriend `generate_series` is fantastically useful, but since its output is not indexed, it restricts the ability to do joins all-at-once (unless the planner is even smarter than I think it is). In the way you are using it, I think it pretty much guarantees at least one Nested Loop, and those are usually bad. Can you explain the _advantage_ over using `BETWEEN`?

Comment: Although the effect is similar, (at least in MSSQL, not 100% sure about Postgre) when you use a WITH construction you're actually NOT using a temp-table. (IMHO CTE stands for 'Complex Temp-table Evasion') You really should try to explicitly create a temp-table for the series, make sure there is an index on the time field and JOIN with that one and see how it affects the query plan; it might affect the order of how things are executed. (or not =)

Comment: `Bitmap Heap Scan on headlines_ngrams hn  (cost=41.12..4359.59 rows=1103 width=66) (actual time=206.634..49273.363 rows=294787 loops=1)
                                               Recheck Cond: ((ngram_hashed_id)::text = (n.hashed_id)::text)` is the hotspot. Why the cast to text? Is there an index available ? Why are the statistics off by a factor ~300 ?

Comment: @wildplasser Recently added a composite index(ngram_hashed_id,headline_hashed_id) which improved the speed for ngram search: http://explain.depesz.com/s/JAI . hashed_id's are MD5 hashes stored as varchars, so maybe that explains the text casting. Now the major issue now is batchtimes_headlines, which has poor performance even with an index.

Comment: Why not just use a serial for a surrogate key? (or cast (part) of the md5 to a bigint ?)

Comment: @AndrewLazarus Thanks for your suggestions on generate_series. I have noticed some improvement when using WHERE BETWEEN, such as better row statistics. The queries still take over 1 minute so I still need to improve performance.

Comment: @wildplasser I use a front-end caching method to speed up inserts without synchronizing with the DB; hashed ids were part of that method. I just re-architected the system to require synchronization, but use serial ids instead. Each key will now be 4 bytes instead of 32 bytes. I'll post an update in a few days, after all the data has been inserted to the new system.

Comment: @wildplasser Changing the column type had a huge performance increase.  Query times range from 100ms to 25s, depending on whether some parts of the join are cached. This is much better than the original 20s - 120s. If you post an answer related to column type, indexes, and speed, i'll accept it. I will now look into clustered indexes, partitioning, etc... to get the last bit of performance.

Comment: I'm a DBA; trust me ... ;-]

Answer (score 1):

This may or may not answer to your question. i cannot comment above, since i dont have 50 rep's as per Stack overflow. :/

My first question is why Inner Join..? This will return you unwanted Columns in your Inner join result. For example in your query when you inner join

`INNER JOIN headlines_ngrams AS hn ON bh.headline_hashed_id = hn.headline_hashed_id`

The result will have two columns with same information which is redundant. so for example if you have 100,000,000 rows, you will have bh.headline_hashed_id and hh.headline_hashed_id 100,000,000 entries in each column. in your query above you are joining 5 tables. Plus you are interested in only

`SELECT SUM(bh.count) AS count,b.time AS batchtime`

so i belive you to use Natural join.

[link] (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_join#Inner_join)

The reason that i can think of why in second attempt you are getting a improved performance is due to cache. People have mentioned above to use temporary table for Generate_series which could be a good option. Plus if you think of using **WITH** in your query then, you should read this article. [link](http://www.sswug.org/articles/viewarticle.aspx?id=18843)

Comment: Great point on excess columns with inner join! And thanks for the WITH article. I'll do some experimenting with these points.